# Unable to install Fedora 23 as UEFI

Tags: linux, boot, usb, fedora

I Downloaded Fedora 23 workstation and created Live USB using these methods.

- using command `# dd if=Fedora-Live-----.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4m &&

  sync`.
- Using Fedora Live USB tool.
- using Rawrite32 on a windows machine.
- using gnome-disk-image-writer.

Basically every method mentioned [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB). which can be done on my existing f22 machine or on my friends windows machine.

When I try to boot from my pendrive I get this issue when I start fedora live
( Image was grainy so I am typing all this, ignore any typing mistake, and I would be skipping few repeated lines and 0x000292 kind of address values)

```
[0.003636] Ignore BGRT: Invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[4.112133] nouveau[ DRM] Pointer to TMDS table invalid.
[ok] Started Plymouth boot screen.
[ok]
[ok[



[8.616233] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[13.xxxxx]usb 1-6: hub failed to enable device, error -62
[18.xxxxx]usb 2-2: device not accepting address 2, error -62

Starting Drakut emergency shell...

warning: /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-23-10 does not exist
warning: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist
generating "/run/initramfs/rdosreport.txt"
```

I have verified ISO checksum given on the fedora site, It is correct.
Also I was able to boot fedora live USB using YUMI tool on windows, But it only works on BIOS mode, and installs Bios-only boot fedora, Not UEFI. I am confused as using command line always worked for me before, and I was able to install F20, F21, F22, all in UEFI mode directly. Please suggest.

**Update :**
I have installed F23 in non-uefi mode, During install I gave 200MiB partition to `/boot/efi` so now I can see that EFI Files are there in the system. But in BIOS Option, Fedora is only listed in Legacy section, not in EFI section. Some help regarding this please.

Comment: Update your system's BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that installing the Uefi software to /boot/efi will not do the trick. It will look good, and you can see all of the software and files in the /boot/efi directory, but it won't work.

The missing step is to MOUNT your new UEFI partition onto the /boot/efi directory. Once the UEFI partition is mounted, then when you install the UEFI software and other files, they will go into the UEFI partition where they can be seen by your hardware's boot mechanism when you reboot your system.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to format the disk (/boot) as a GPT with fat32.

Im running into the same issue, but I'm installing it beside manjaro that successfully installed as uefi. Similar issue as you though, mine gives me an error when trying to install...

"Your BIOS-based system needs a special partition to boot from a GPT disk label. To continue, please create a 1MB 'biosboot' type partition..."

I'm assuming we need to modify Grub in order for us to boot in "secure boot (uefi mode).

Comment: Using tools already format usb with fat32. Installation has added an EFI partition and EFI files. But F23 is listed only in Legacy section, not in EFI section.